# Search with multiple inputs in kohana 3.0 and ORM

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3

I want to build a search with four search terms. I'm using Kohana 3.0.7 and using ORM. In plain SQL, I can check if a particular field is set and the add it in the query. My query is as follows -

```
$search_sql = "Select E.*, B.*
                       from events as E
                       INNER JOIN businesses as B
                       on E.business_id = B.id
                       ";
        if(!empty($date_term)) {
        $search_sql .=" where E.start_time like '%".$date_term."%'";
        }
        else {
        $search_sql .=" where E.start_time like '".date('Y-m-d')."%'";
        }
        if(!empty($keyword_term)) {         
            $search_sql .=" AND E.title like '%".$keyword_term."%'";
                $search_sql .=" OR B.description like '%".$keyword_term."%'"; 
                     }
        if(!empty($location_term)) {
            $search_sql .=" AND B.city like '%".$location_term."%'";
            $search_sql .=" OR B.state like '%".$location_term."%'"; 
        }
        if(!empty($zip_term)) {
            $search_sql .=" AND B.zip_code like '%".$zip_term."%'";
        }
```

If I run this query as

```
              $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT,$search_sql);
              $res_query = $query->execute();
```

I'm not able to access the object and its methods which I can return if I run this query in ORM way. But I'm not able to check the fields and add them in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried like this:

```
$query = DB::query(Database::SELECT,$search_sql);
$res_query = $query->as_object()->execute();
```

Also you don't have to use plain SQL for this - ORM or Query Builder can also do it (edited to have ORM object returned):

```
    $query = ORM::factory('event')
            ->join(array('businesses', 'B'), 'INNER')
            ->on('event.business_id', '=', 'B.id')
            ->where_open();

    if(!empty($date_term)) {
        $query->where('event.start_time', 'LIKE', '%' . $date_term . '%');
    }
    else {
        $query->where('event.start_time', 'LIKE', date('Y-m-d') . '%');
    }

    if(!empty($keyword_term)) {   
        $query->where_open(); // Add brackets, don't know if needed
        $query->where('event.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword_term . '%');
        $query->or_where('B.description', 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword_term . '%');
        $query->where_close(); 
    }

    if(!empty($location_term)) {
        $query->where_open(); // Add brackets, don't know if needed
        $query->where('B.city', 'LIKE', '%' . $location_term . '%');
        $query->or_where('B.state', 'LIKE', '%' . $location_term . '%');
        $query->where_close();
    }

    if(!empty($zip_term)) {
        $query->where('B.zip', 'LIKE', '%' . $zip_term . '%');
    }
    $query->where_close()->find_all();
```

Comment: `->as_object()` returns just an object, not ORM model. You need `->as_object('event')` for example, but I dont think it will work.

Comment: Should be easy enough now to switch to ORM code (edited my answer), as you can mix ORM with Query builder :)

Comment: This works but if I try like this -  $query->count(), it gives me error saying - "Invalid method count called in Model_Event". I need the count to display the pagination. :(

Comment: You need to call count on ORM object, not DB Builder, like this: $result = $query->where_close()->find_all(); $count = $result->count();